# In vNet integration of App service i am getting "Only supports nested resources." error so that unable to disconnect the vNets how to fix it

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, vnet

In vNet integration of App service i am getting "Only supports nested resources." error so that unable to disconnect the vNets how to fix it .

[image]

Disconnecting vNet from azure app services

Comment: can you provide more details on VNet configuration?

Comment: Make sure the vNet is not using by any Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0):

> In vNet integration of App service i am getting "Only supports nested resources." error so that unable to disconnect the vNets how to fix it

If the `'Only supports nested resources'` error is present, you will likely encounter issues when trying to disconnect the **vNet** from the **App Service** using the `UI`.

To resolve the error, you can use below`Azure CLI` commands to disconnect the `Vnet` from your `App Service`.

I have followed this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/vnet-integration?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-vnet-integration-remove) as a reference to disconnect the **Vnet** from **App service** using `Azure CLI`.

**Azure CLI**

```
 $webAppName = "<webappname>"
 $resourceGroupName = "<resourceGroupName>"
 $webApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $webAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName   
 # Disconnect the vNet by setting the vNet name and resource group to empty
 az webapp vnet-integration remove -g "<resourceGroupName>" -n "<webappname>"
 Write-Host "The vNet has been disconnected from the App Service $webAppName ."
```

**Output:**

[image]

Vnet disconnect from App Service as below.

[image]